# $_POST variables not pulling over

Tags: php, mysql, post

Still working on a simple web app, but am running into an issue where $_POST variables aren't pulling over.

edit.php:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styles.css" media="screen" />
  <title>Inventory</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
include 'includes/dbconnect.php';

$inven_id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT
            * 
          FROM 
            inventory 
          INNER JOIN 
            products 
          ON 
            inventory.sku=products.sku 
          WHERE 
            inventory.id = '$inven_id'"; 


$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<form method="POST" action="submitchanges.php" />

<table>

<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $inven_id ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Species:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="species" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" readonly="readonly" size="35" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>SKU:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="sku" value="<?php echo $row['sku']; ?>" readonly="readonly" size="35" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Category:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $row['category']; ?>" readonly="readonly" size="35" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Fry Count:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="frycount" value="<?php echo $row['quantityfry']; ?>" size="35" maxlength="4" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Juvie Count:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="juviecount" value="<?php echo $row['quantityjuv']; ?>" size="35" maxlength="4" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Adult Count:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="adultcount" value="<?php echo $row['quantityadult']; ?>" size="35" maxlength="4" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Notes:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="notes" value="<?php echo $row['notes']; ?>" size="35" maxlength="255" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Location:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $row['location']; ?>" size="35" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Owner:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="owner" value="<?php echo $row['owner']; ?>" size="35" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

submitchanges.php:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/styles.css" media="screen" />
  <title>Inventory</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
include 'includes/dbconnect.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$quantityfry = $_POST['frycount'];
$quantityjuv = $_POST['juviecount'];
$quantityadult = $_POST['adultcount'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$owner = $_POST['owner'];

$query="UPDATE
          inventory
        SET
          quantityfry = '$quantityfry',
          quantityjuv = '$quantityjuv',
          quantityadult = '$quantityadult',
          notes = '$notes',
          location = '$location',
          owner = '$owner'
        WHERE
          id='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if ($result)
{
  echo "Successful!";
  echo "<BR>";
  echo "<a href='index.php'>View result</a>";
}

else

{
  echo "ERROR!";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It seems some variables (the three quantity*) aren't pulling over properly.  When I add this into my submitchanges.php, it doesn't display any output:

```
echo $_POST['quantityfry'];
echo $_POST['quantityjuv'];
echo $_POST['quantityadult'];
```

However, this does provide the expected output:

```
echo $_POST['notes'];
echo $_POST['location'];
echo $_POST['owner'];
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: PHP files updated to reflect discussed changes, and now they work as I want.

Comment: You need to make sure that the form input names are right - you're using `<input name="fry count">`, so that's the field you need to look for in `$_POST`

Comment: Do you mean `$_GET["id"];` instead of `$_GET[id];`  ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: While you don't have an element named `quantityfry` in your form, `$_POST['quantityfry']` won't display any output. So where is the problem?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you have to work with instead of guessing.

Comment: **POST variables cannot contain spaces, including form input names.**

Comment: the andrewsi answer is right. <input type="text" name="adult count" then echo $_POST['quantityadult']; is nonsense

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks.  I have updated both files, and the echo is now working.

Now, however, MySQL isn't being updated when submitchanges.php runs.

Comment: Did you reload everything? You might have something in your cache that's keep the old values. @tycoonbob Also check your `WHERE
          id='$id'";` if it's an integer, try and test it with an existing ID number, I.e.: `WHERE
          id=1";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Looking directly at the Table Data, I can see that none of the values have been updated.

Comment: None of the values will be updated, even if **ONE** value is incorrect. Did you try what I suggested? @tycoonbob I edited my comment above, so you may not have seen it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have not tried that yet, but I did add `echo $id;` to `submitchanges.php` and noticed that it returns a value of 36.  That line in my table is actually 1 (I've only got two rows of data in this particular table).  Where it's getting 36 from, I have no idea.

When I set id='1'"; in my query, it works like it should.

Comment: Then, I'm questioning this line `WHERE 
            inventory.id = '$inven_id'";` why isn't it matching your UPDATE codes? @tycoonbob Something doesn't match. Did you do a `var_dump($_GET);` or `var_dump();` on all variables?

Comment: `36` may be pulling it from an ID number, do you have 36 ID's?

Comment: No, there are only 2 rows in that table.  `echo $inven_id;` returned the correct row value, in edit.php.  I'm guessing something is wrong with my first input field.

Comment: *"I have not tried that yet, but I did add echo $id;"* Then try it, I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: I did try adding my row id directly into the update query, and it worked like it should.

Comment: Then try `WHERE
          id=$id";` without the quotes around `$id` or `WHERE
          id='" . $id . "' ";`

Comment: The problem is with this:
`<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /></td>`
When I change the `type` to `type=text`, it shows a value of `36` instead of the expect value of `1`.

Comment: I don't know man, I'm baffled. Those `GET`s can be a pain in the neck. The only thing I can suggest is to use GET instead of POST in this `$id = $_POST['id'];` to `$id = $_GET['id'];` see if that makes it kick in, but I doubt it very much. Or change `$inven_id = $_GET['id'];` to `$inven_id = $_POST['id'];` but again, a big doubt.

Comment: `<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $inven_id ?>" /></td>` 
Setting it to this works.  

So I think I figured out what's going on though.  This that input set to `echo $row['id'];`, it's working...just not as I wanted.  The id that it's pulling (`36`, in this case) is the id (Primary Key) for a different table in my DB...the table that stores all the product information.  Ergo, it was working -- just not like I wanted.  What I have now works.

Comment: Well, it's a solution nonetheless.

Comment: OP has been updated to reflect working PHP files.  Now to make them more secure.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just for the heck of it, try this `WHERE id = $_GET[id]`

Comment: Plus, using [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) could also be a solution to all this, and just assign your GET `id`, to a session variable.

Comment: `WHERE id = $_GET[id]` did not work.

Comment: Try this. Put `session_start();` inside ALL your pages under your opening `<?php` tag. Then 

put this only in your `edit.php` page --- `session_start(); if (isset($_GET['id'])){ $_SESSION['id_number'] = $id; }` just above `$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));` you may need to play around with it a bit, but sessions will work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I appreciate your continued effort in this, but what benefit would I have by using `session_start();` instead of what I have, since it works?  I'll definitely give it a try and make the change if it's beneficial, but I have a few others items to get working on this form today (i.e., table drop down from db enum fields, login piece, etc).

Comment: Or change your `value="<?php echo $inven_id ?>"` to `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>` and you're welcome. Sessions are very powerful, and facilitate a lot of complicated tasks.

Comment: `$inven_id = $_GET['id'];` is already being run, which is why I would think `value="<?php echo $inven_id ?>"` makes more sense, instead of running $_GET again.  I'm new to WebDev, but in scripting (batch, PoSH, VB) it's usually best practice to set things to variables and reference those variables when needed.  Is that not the case with PHP?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using GET for a variable. GETs are populated when accessed from the browser, such as `submit.php?variable&other_var` is that what you're doing to access the ID?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what's happening. `index.php` runs a query and populates a table, and to the right of each row is a link to edit that calls `./edit.php?id=x` where x is the id (PK) of one of my DB tables.

Comment: Try this then: `inventory.id = '$_GET[inven_id]'";` or `inventory.id = '$_GET['inven_id']'";`

Comment: Actually, I meant `inventory.id = '$_GET[id]'";` or `inventory.id = '" . $_GET[id] . "'";` might have to put single quotes around `id`

Comment: Also have a look [**at this answer on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19551490/1415724) you probably could use `WHERE inventory.id = ?";` also, which may be the case. Heck, something is bound to give! [**Then on the same page**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19552556/1415724) which could be an issue in your case. I.e.: `$inven_id = (int) $_GET['id'];`

Answer (score 2):

The name you use in the form does not match the name of the field you try to get from $_POST:

```
 name="fry count"
```

should be

```
name="quantityfry"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that $_POST was looking for "input name" data.  It makes sense now, and the variables are pulling over correctly.  The OP has been updated to reflect my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML inputs are broken, depending on the browser you are using, this might be the cause of the data not being posted correctly.

For example

```
<input //... readonly="readonly" size="35"
```

Requires an closing HTML tag

```
<input //... readonly="readonly" size="35"/>
```

Also I believe that variables posted with a space will only be available in the `$_POST` superglobal with an underscore.

So `fry count` will be `$_POST['fry_count']`

It therefore makes sense to use that standard naming conventions for your input elements (which is to use underscores `_` within the HTML directly)

```
<input type="text" name="fry_count"
```

**Edit** The [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) states

> > **Note:** Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example  becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].

Comment: Thanks for catching the input fields.  It's working in Chrome, but I can see where I fudged that up.

Answer (score 0):

you write this variable on `submitchanges.php:` file:

```
$quantityfry = $_POST['quantityfry'];
$quantityjuv = $_POST['quantityjuv'];
$quantityadult = $_POST['quantityadult'];
```

but in `edit.php:`

no field name with `quantityfry,quantityjuv,quantityadult`(in edit.php)

so change the one of the file variable and make it same in both pages.

I think you better change variable in `submitchanges.php`.

it may be like this:

```
$quantityfry = $_POST['frycount'];
$quantityjuv = $_POST['juviecount'];
$quantityadult = $_POST['adultcount'];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that $_POST was looking for "input name" data.  It makes sense now, and the variables are pulling over correctly.  The OP has been updated to reflect my changes.